# Fscanf integers from file while ignoring surrounding characters

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I'm trying to read a series of integers from a text file that is formatted as follows:

```
int1
int2
int3
int4
int99
```

ie. every integer has the same string in front of it, in this case 'int'.

I've tried the following code, but the program only prints the first integer and then ends.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
int num;
while (fscanf(fp, "int%d", &num) == 1)
    printf("%d\n", num);

fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding a space after %d will do the job.

```
  (fscanf(fp1,"int%d ", &num)==1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you explain why this works? I was under the assumption that fscanf matches whitespace even if it isn't in the format given.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not consuming the new line character and it is left out in the input stream.

Just change your `fscanf` as below.

```
fscanf(fp, "int%d\n", &num) == 1
                 ^^-->read new line
```